# Using range.find to create a chart - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

[image]I have code that searches for a number in a range(Column A which includes merged cells) from a userform textbox, then it creates a graph based off of that number. I am having trouble with adding the correct axis values. Based off that number found, it will create a graph with the values to the right of the number in column A.

Col A and B will be the x axis and C , D, F will be the y axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Trend")
Dim LastRow As Long, partnum As String, findpart As Range
Dim partChart As Chart
Dim chartWorkSheet As Worksheet

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
partnum = TextBox1.Value


If Not Application.IsNA(Application.Match(partnum, Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
    Set findpart = Cells(Application.Match(partnum, Range("A:A"), 0), 1)

    ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add

    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "QTY Left"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "Trend!"

'''                'Titles
'''                .HasTitle = True
'''                .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Scatter Chart"
'''                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
'''                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text=*emphasized text*"X values"
'''                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
'''                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Y values"
'''                .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
'''
'''                'Formatting
'''                .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
'''                .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
'''                .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
'''                .HasLegend = False
''
    End With
Else
    MsgBox ("Part Number Not Found!")
End If

Unload Me

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Some sample data and showing the expected output would help here.

Comment: I attached a screenshot